# Meteor afQuickField with onfocus can't find function

Tags: javascript, meteor, onfocus

I'm trying to implement a dynamic help field that changes when the focus changes with Meteor AutoForms (similar to the "Similar Questions" box that appears to the right when you ask a question here). But when the field gets focus I get "ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined".

I've tried defining the myFunc as a non-wrapped function and a template helper in my .js file and as a `<script>` wrapped function in the .html file and even as an in-line function as part of the onfocus (which is really ugly and fails because it can't find the title and text arrays that are in the .js file), but still get the ReferenceError. Same problem with onclick. I've also tried a Template focus or click event (this one never fires)

Sample code below. I've left out all of the `<div>s` for clarity, but the form displays properly in the actual code, its just the onfocus attribute that isn't working.

.html

```
<template name="updateProfileForm">
    {{#autoForm id="updateProfileForm" collection="Meteor.users" doc=currentUser type="update"}}
    {{> afQuickField
        name="emails.1.address"
        id="secondaryEmail"
        label='Secondary Email'
        onfocus='ProfileUpdateHelp("secondary")'}}
</template>
```

.js

```
    Template.updateProfileForm.helpers ({
      ProfileUpdateHelp: function(fieldName) {
       // console.log("This:", this);
       //  console.log("instance():", instance());
        TemplateVar.set('helpTitle', profileUpdateHelpTitles[fieldName]);
        TemplateVar.set('helpText', profileUpdateHelpTexts[fieldName]);
      },
    });

profileUpdateHelpTitles = {
  primary: "Primary email address",
  secondary: "Secondary email address",
};
profileUpdateHelpTexts = {
  primary: "Primary email address help",
  secondary: "Secondary email address help",
};
```

I also tried with events and none of them fire (I'd expect all 3 to fire):

```
Template.updateProfileForm.events({
    "click #secondaryEmail": function(e) {
        alert("Click");
    },
    "focus #secondaryEmail": function(e) {
        alert("focus");
    },
    "blur #secondaryEmail": function(e) {
        alert("blur");
    }, 
});
```

Comment: Please try with events instead of helper.

Comment: Template.updateProfileForm.events ({
 'blur #secondaryEmail': function(events){ /* Do whatever you want to do */ }
})

Comment: Events never fire. See editted post above.

Answer (score 1):

**Success!!!**

So the issue was much larger than events not firing. Neither events or helpers in the .js file were being executed. The problem turned out to be with my attempt to add support for prerender.io. The prerenderio object wasn't defined so references to it were throwing errors. Why this caused template helpers and events to not work in a different file I'm guessing has to do with load order. But removing the references to the undefined object caused my helpers and events to start working!

---

**EDIT:**

So it turns out that removing the undefined object wasn't the only change I made and in fact wasn't the fix. I had also declared

```
import { Template } from 'Meteor/Meteor'
```

which is obviously not the place to import from. This caused Template to become "something else" which caused anything starting with Template. (helpers, events, etc) to become non-existent. The correct import is of course

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
```

If anyone understands the technical details of why the bad import behaved the way it did (no compile or run-time errors), please leave them in a comment to enlighten the rest of us. Thanks.

**END EDIT**

---

For anyone who comes here looking for how to get onfocus working here is the code. This will fire on all input fields as well as buttons contained in the form. If you want just a single input field then use #fieldId instead of #formId.

```
Template.updateProfileForm.events({
  "focus #updateProfileForm": function(e) {
    const fieldId = e.target.id;
  },
});
```

Comment: @halfer, why did you take the "Solved" out of the title? I found the underlying problem that made it all work.